# Hibernate xml column definition

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

so this seems to be a bit of a hack but I've been looking at this code too long. I have a table that's id is a bpchar in postgres. The pojo is looking for a string and I am getting an error when the xml finds a bpchar when it is expecting a varchar. My question is how do I either add a columnDefinition in either the pojo or the xml mapping file. The EO doesn't compile with the @column annontation and the xml can't be parsed when I try to add columnDefinition on an id. Any help or thoughts

xml mapping file:

```
<class name="POSTGRES.Customers" table="customers" schema="public">
        <id name="custId" type="string">
            <column name="CustID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="companyName" type="string">
            <column name="CompanyName" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

pojo:

```
public String getCustId() {
        return this.custId;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `sql-type="bpchar"` appears to have fixed the issue in the `xml`.